# FixedPoint doesn't work

Tags: iteration

Do you know why it doesn't print any result?I set intial value is 0.1,

```
h[x_] = Sin[x];

(*Plot[{x,h[x]},{x,1,50}]*)

FixedPoint[h[#] &, 0.1];
```

Comment: Let me warn you at the outset: altho $0$ is a known fixed point of $\sin$, it will take a whole long while to reach it. Gray and Glynn did some *Mathematica* experiments on this subject in their book. (For giggles, look at the result of `Plot[Nest[Sin, x, 1*^4], {x, 0, 2 π}]`.)

Comment: Thx. Actually, what I want is to get the fixed point and check if they are stable or unstable. So I think to do that, I should start with "Fixedpoint" syntax, after it works then try "FixedpointList" to print some numbers which are closed to fixed point. Sin(x)=x is one equation, the other is x^2-2=x. the fixed point of x^2-2=x, is x=2 or x=-1, I want to try 1.9,2.1 some thing like that to test if this is stable or unstable point by plotting result. But I am stuck in the first step.

Comment: I think you should use [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) instead of [`FixedPoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPoint.html) to discover the fixed points: `Solve[h[x] == x, x, Reals]` gives only the solution $x=0$ (but in triplicate). For the other problem, `Solve[x^2 - 2 == x, x, Reals]` gives your desired two fixed points.

Comment: Then, after having discovered the fixed points, you can study their stability by calculating the derivative of `h`: With `S = Solve[h[x]==x, x, Reals]` you can evaluate `Abs[h'[x]] /. S` and see for which points the derivative is less than 1 (stable), more than 1 (unstable), or exactly 1 (need more information). [See here for an extended discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_theory).

Answer (score 6):

As Bill said by looking at

```
NestList[Sin[#] &, 0.1, 10000]
ListPlot[%]
```

[image: NestList convergence]

you can see how slowly this converges. Let's get a more quantified idea how slow!

Every iteration we push the last value `x` to `Sin[x]`. But `Sin[x]` itself gets closer to `x` as we approach zero, so what will happen there? We can look at the taylor series expansion to get the leading term

```
Series[Sin[x] - x, {x, 0, 3}]
```

> -(x^3/6)+O[x]^4

which is cubic. Ideally to get an analytic solution to an arbitrary index term in our sequence we would like the solution to that by calling

```
RSolve[{a[n+1]==a[n]-a[n]^3/6,a[0]==1/10},a,n]
```

but `RSolve` doesn't know how to solve that. But looking at our earlier plot, approximating this by a continuous function shouldn't be too bad, so let's try that:

```
DSolve[{a'[x] == -(a[x]^3/6), a[0] == 1/10}, a[x], x]
```

> {{a[x] -> Sqrt[3]/Sqrt[300 + x]}}

```
Plot[Sqrt[3]/Sqrt[300 + x], {x, 0, 10000}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.1}, PlotStyle -> Orange]
```

[image: DSolve solution]

Which looks almost exactly as our `NestList` result, nice!

So how long will it take to get to the fixed point then? When using the default `$MachinePrecision` it will take us

```
Solve[Sqrt[3]/Sqrt[300 + x] == $MachineEpsilon, x]
```

> {{x -> 6.08472*10^31}}

iterations to get to `$MachineEpsilon` close to zero. My machine can do roughly 20 million `Nest` iterations per second so this would take approximately `10^17` years! Probably it would take a lot longer even, because `$MachineEpsilon` is only the smallest difference that is distinguishable from 1 that will not be rounded, but close to zero we have a lot more precision since we can use negative exponents downto $2^{-127}$ and then we can still go down $2^{-23}$ more by using [denormalized numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number). So until we get to a small number near zero where the decrement `-a[x]^3/6` will be rounded down to zero will essentially and practically take forever :)

But by using our approximate solution we can at least see that the fixed point is zero as expected:

```
Limit[Sqrt[3]/Sqrt[300 + x], x -> Infinity]
```

> 0

Answer (score 3):

As J.M. points out, the convergence is very slow. You can see this by comparing:

```
FixedPoint[h[#] &, 0.01, 2000]
```

with

```
FixedPoint[h[#] &, 0.01, 2000000]
```

where the third parameter specifies a max number of iterations.

If you want to find the fixed point of Sin[x]==x, it may be easiest to do it symbolically. For example:

```
FindInstance[Sin[x] == x, x]
{{x -> 0}}
```

gives the answer immediately. To see the iterates numerically, you can use

```
NestList[Sin[#] &, 0.1, 1000]
```

but this still converges very slowly towards 0.

(Thanks to J.M. for seeing that I had used the wrong function earlier.)

Comment: Thx. Actually, what I want is to get the fixed point and check if they are stable or unstable. So I think to do that, I should start with "Fixedpoint" syntax, after it works then try "FixedpointList" to print some numbers which are closed to fixed point. Sin(x)=x is one equation, the other is x^2-2=x. the fixed point of x^2-2=x, is x=2 or x=-1, I want to try 1.9,2.1 some thing like that to test if this is stable or unstable point by plotting result. But I am stuck in the first step.

Comment: Erik -- I'm not sure that the question of stability makes sense without more information. What is it that you are examining the stability of?

Comment: for example, if x=1.9, if we iterate f(x)=x^2-2, how it will change, and I would like to know how to implement this by using mathmatica code.

Comment: For your polynomial f, you can see the iterates in many ways. One way is: NestList[#^2 - 2 &, 1.9, 10], analogous to the NestList above.

Comment: As a slight correction: in `NestList[Sin[#] - # &, 0.1, 10]` you are iterating $\sin x -x$ and not $\sin x$ as in the OP.